# ModalPopupExtender adding scrollbars in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, modalpopupextender

Whenever I show a ModalPopupExtender on my Sharepoint site, the popup shown creates both horizontal and vertical scrollbars.  If you scroll all the way to the end of the page, the scrollbar refreshes, and there is more page to scroll through.  Basically, I think the popup is setting its bounds beyond the end of the page.  Has anyone run into this?  Searching Google, it seems this may be a known problem, but I haven't found a good solution that doesn't include recompiling AJAX, which my boss will not allow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the TargetControl is of sufficient size to hold everything you put in it?  If so, try:

- Set CSS overflow:hidden;
- If the target control is a Panel, set scrollbars="none". Otherwise, put it in a panel and try it.

Answer (score 3):

Hacky answer would be to grab the IE Developer Toolbar, find the tag that has the scrollbar, and alter your CSS file to add the overflow:hidden property to it.